# extract month and year in oracle

Tags: oracle, to-char

Why does below query work successfully?

```
select to_char(sysdate,'MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

But the following queries give an `invalid number` error:

```
select to_char('28-JUL-17','MM-YYYY') from dual;
select  to_char('7/28/2017','MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

Though, below query gives you the same date format.

```
select sysdate from dual; -- 7/28/2017 11:29:01 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

TO_CHAR function accepts only date or number. Maybe you can try this

```
select to_char(to_date('28-JUL-17', 'DD-MON-YY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? There's nothing wrong with this advice, and it was posted so close to over similar advices that it's unlikely to be plagiarism

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if you're planning to convert a bunch of dates to strings so you can look for all records in a certain month of a certain year, be aware that the TRUNC function can be used to reduce the precision of a date (e.g. to "month and year"). The following query pulls all records created this month, from the table. It should be faster than converting dates to char and doing string comparison..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE trunc(create_date, 'MON') = trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
```

Comment: Are you sure trunc is faster than to_char or to_date while doing date comparison?

Comment: Yep, though I caught a recent blog post from Tom Kyte that the difference isn't as pronounced these days. Faster, of course, is not to manipulate your table data at all, because that stops (non function based) indexes working- use a date range instead and use the table data as is

Answer (score 1):

Because function `TO_CHAR()` accepts date or timestamp values. However, neither `'28-JUL-17'` nor `'7/28/2017'` are dates or timestamps - they are **STRINGS**.

Oracle gently tries to convert these stings into `DATE` values. This implicit conversion may work or may fail, it depends on your current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, resp. `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` settings.

As given already in other answers you have to convert the string explicitly:

```
TO_DATE('28-JUL-17', 'DD-MON-RR')
TO_DATE('7/28/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the inputs.

Comment: @AdarshJoshi: Don't forget to upvote the answers that you found helpful and to accept the one that best solved your problem. If you haven't seen that section of the help center, you might find it [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). :)

Answer (score 0):

`to_char()` isn't expecting you to start with a `char` value. If you really want that to work, you'll need to wrap it around a `to_date()` function.

```
to_char(
  to_date(
    '28-JUL-17'
    , 'DD-Mon-YY'
   )
  ,'MM-YYYY'
)
```

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to find month-year from a specific date, but I want to use only one function at a time. i.e. to_char or to_date

Comment: @AdarshJoshi: Well, if you pass the input as a string instead of a date, you're going to have to convert it to a date, before you can convert it to a different string. There's no way around that. So long as you're not qualifying on this in the `where` clause, the performance impact should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I am using it in where clause, comparing date from a column to a particular month-year combination(string like: 07-2017). Will it impact the performance. I don't think so.

Comment: @AdarshJoshi: as compared to actually storing the data in a proper date format? Yes, it'll impact performance. That being said, unless you have a lot of data, it'll probably do well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect mask, for more information read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

The correct one should be:

```
select to_char(to_date('28-JUL-17','DD-MON-YY'), 'MON-YY') from dual;
```

You can also extract the month using [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
select EXTRACT (MONTH FROM to_date('28-JUL-17','DD-MON-YY')) from dual;
```

Cheers

Comment: First query is fine, but second one will give you only month, not a month- year combination.

Comment: Exactly as I said ... this was just an example, EXTRACT can be used for many things - check the link.